# Nested dictionary access is returning a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

The issue I'm having is that when i try to access the values within a nested dictionary, i cannot because it's returning a list instead of a dictionary.

I have a .json file with this format;

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "1": {
                "1": "value",
                "2": "value"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I load the .json file, and access the value i want by using this function

```
def load_json(fn):
    with open(fn) as pf:
        data = json.load(pf)
        return data['users']['1']['2']
```

If i simply do `return data` it is a dictionary, but if try to access further by adding `['users']`, it turns into a list and will give an index error if i try to access key #1 or #2 inside of that..

My objective is to obtain the value of the nested key #2 for example, ideally without having loop through it.

Comment: `data['users']` is a list of nested dictionaries, you need to use the list index before the dictionary keys i.e. `data['users'][0]['1']['2']`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON contains an array (Python `list`) wrapping the inner `dict`s (that's what the `[` and `]` in your JSON indicate). All you need to do is change:

```
    return data['users']['1']['2']
```

to:

```
    return data['users'][0]['1']['2']
                      # ^^^ Added
```

to index the `list` to get into the inner `dict`s.

Answer (score 0):

given your data structure, and following it down :

- `data` is a dictionary - with one key 'users' and a value of a list
- `data['users']` is a list - with one entry
- `data['users'][0]` is a dictionary - with one key '1' and a value of a dictionary
- `data['users'][0][1]` is a dictionary - with two keys '1' and '2'

So you need to do do :

```
def load_json(fn):
    with open(fn) as pf:
        data = json.load(pf)
        return data['users'][0]['1']['2']
```